# JS: replacing all occurrences of a word in html with <span> element ONLY for p, span & divs. Not working if parent node contains the word

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html:

```
<div>
hello world
<p>
the world is round
<img src="domain.com/world.jpg">
</p>
</div>
```

And want to replace the word "world" (or mixed case variants thereof) with `<span style='color:red;'>BARFOO</span>` but only in `<p>`, `<div>` and a few other specific elements.

In the following code, it changes the text in the `<div>`, but not in the `<p>`. A replace operation is done (on something), but does not show up in the browser's html.

If I just supply `p` to `querySelectorAll`, then repeat again for `<div>`, it works fine.

I am thinking that once the code processes the `<div>` and finds that it has a child element(s), when that element(s) is put back into the html string, then the element reference for the `<p>` is lost.

jsfiddle is set up here https://jsfiddle.net/limeygent/t5q8ch23/12/ with more debug statements.

Any thoughts on what is happening & how to fix? (js only solution please)

```
var newspan = "<span style='color:red;'>BOOFAR</span>";

var regExNameSearch = new RegExp('World','gi');
var lc= 'World'.toLowerCase();

const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p, span, div, strong, h1, h2, h3, h4')).filter(
          (element) => {
            for (let child of element.childNodes) {
              if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && child.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(lc)) {
                console.log('found ' + child.textContent);
                let parent = child.parentNode;
                let html = parent.innerHTML;

                // Find all the child elements in the element
                var excludeElements = parent.querySelectorAll('*');

                if (excludeElements.length == 0){
                    console.log('no child elements');
                    parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace(regExNameSearch, newspan);
                    // (also tried this) parent.innerHTML = html;
                }else{

                    // Replace the text of each child element with placeholder
                    excludeElements.forEach(excludeElement => {
                        console.log('phase 1 - replacing - BEFORE');
                        html = html.replace(excludeElement.outerHTML, 'FOOBAR');
                        console.log('phase 1 - replacing - AFTER');
                    });
                    html = html.replace(regExNameSearch, newspan);

                    // Replace the text of each child element back to its original HTML
                    excludeElements.forEach(excludeElement => {
                        console.log('phase 2 - replacing - BEFORE:');
                        html = html.replace('FOOBAR', excludeElement.outerHTML);
                        console.log('phase 2 - replacing - AFTER:');
                    });

                    // Update the element's innerHTML with the updated HTML
                    parent.innerHTML = html;
                    
                }
                  return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        );
```

**edit**: if you supply an answer recc. editing the innerHTML, make sure it doesn't affect any child nodes. The code I present here got super complex because I had to avoid editing anything further inside the node.
Oh, and if you present reccs from chatGPT (while it can be useful), please test what you post first ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure but when you replace world the first time you replace it with: hello <span style='color:red;'>BOOFAR</span>
<p>
the world is round
<img src="domain.com/world.jpg">
</p>  that p tag now is not in your node list

Comment: @DCR interesting thought - the `<p>` is still intact though.

`<div>
hello <span style="color:red;">BOOFAR</span>
<p>
the world is round
<img src="domain.com/world.jpg">
</p>
</div>`

Comment: @DCR, your answer was deleted before I could ask questions on it. It worked, but only if the "hello world" was wrapped in its own `<div> ... </div>` The code was very close to my posted code. Looking forward to your new answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you use your code and wrap hello world it works but I'm still trying to figure out why it doesn't work when you don't.  If you figure it out first please post it

Comment: @DCR , with the help of a friend, I think I found the issue. Here's what Rob had to say:
document.querySelectorAll returns a static nodelist which is accurate when the function is called but isn't accurate if the document is changed. Using .innerHTML to make the replacement of "world" deletes and recreates all existing content in the tag including the <p> tag and its contents the <p> tag that is now on the page is a completely new one that isn't referenced by the node returned by document.querySelectorAll

Depth-first traversal (pre-order), then reverse the array seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) API to achieve the desired results.

The essential logic is this:

Iterate [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes that meet the specified criteria: the text content matches the case-insensitive regular expression pattern and the node is the direct child (or, if desired, a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)) of an element that [matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) your selector.

For each matched text node: [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) it from its parent, but first [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the node's text content on the regular expression pattern, and for each resulting string:

- If it is non-empty, re-[insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) it into the parent node (just before the matched node) as a new text node. Before each string (except the first): create a copy of your substitute `<span>` node and insert it as well.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcqIBQYAeADlgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2qA5gPwWpRYxh2ASgppMOVIiKlEAbwBQiRDGD4AhNKxDEUABZZ6iMBjqIAolgNY8bYQG55AX3nzQkWAkQQsGZFAwAKkRQAHJwACYYAGIwADb+WFFIeD7s0hQAShjsZiTMyJAYvHBYAMoYsRjQJTx8AsIUeP6EoREYFEEt2gC8AHxGICwARthyiog+UCBYyU3BYZEdwSIDw6N9Y0pKKup441s6820AdM1QAMII-mBQ+1sAZPcT2dKnRVBzLQsYby2XNxgbkI7kJtJNpkhvjF4thjlEAJIAGQCZgyAH0MmYAFJmc4BBx3AD0hMQATgiGAAnCKDAAE9WH4ILp6jSIO8SvhaLgAFYgXg6XQYRDhGA+aCIYjIHxAshEkkQBD8gBuyFiMGp3UQACE4HBKgVPq1IsdJdKoGZKixAVBOMcILE4JheHgCmzimUKlUoCVQQ4DgqwMrVerEJqzt8TVLrRaMFabraWIzBagXYV3eVKtUtH6tjs8Cq1eEwRgpjNEFC4gk4UiUeiAILnc5mAAK+JcB3BZYrMKw1eRqIx2NxbaUjiEDmcrnA0HgSG8vn8pRAQ14MCm-m++BWAAkAgBZRGlSVgGNx3AKJQB-moY+h4VwCCDa12nx+DCn614ABEN4KX-H4y-mAvwXFc1p3l+Wp1hkUQAPKwV+OZAccvC0pUKEls2BjENgUC0t+CoOlgX7MF+PjhP+OadkgQETi4bgzp4fAFKgwAlCwnRGkKeC0Is5ZtMwqTpIgWQ5CQKxKnAIYXl4irnqa1rfMwZz-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-icdn2BJHgOt63LZiK8wrcy2iBtG3iJtCI4peILlSiVLgWl3oHlVHJENUBXQnPcRdotKMSiB1uEKqFAKQoBFHsexPHWAAOSSGlGVPbwb6ICM-2sCAUB+CyehCo+ljgVpsr+nJrCxuSTUWlcY0yFGGOgs8vhtAXgcZigYNocTngDK0LMu5Sx7piBWzY6ZOBcImAQC8gA)

```ts
function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg);
}

function createTextNodeFilterFn (regexp: RegExp, ancestorSelector: string): (textNode: Text) => number {
  return ((textNode: Text): number => {
    if (!(
      textNode.textContent
      && regexp.test(textNode.textContent)
    )) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;

    // To find any matching ancestor (not just the direct parent):
    // const valid = Boolean(textNode.parentElement?.closest(ancestorSelector));
    const valid = textNode.parentElement?.matches(ancestorSelector);
    if (valid) return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;

    return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  });
}

function createSubstituteNode (): HTMLSpanElement {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = "BARFOO";
  span.style.setProperty("color", "red");
  return span;
}

function transformTextNode (node: Node, regexp: RegExp): void {
  const {parentNode, textContent} = node;
  assert(parentNode, "Parent node not found");
  assert(textContent, "Text content not found");

  const iter = textContent.split(regexp)[Symbol.iterator]();

  const firstResult = iter.next();
  if (firstResult.done) return;
  if (firstResult.value.length > 0) {
    parentNode.insertBefore(new Text(firstResult.value), node);
  }

  for (const str of iter) {
    parentNode.insertBefore(createSubstituteNode(), node);
    if (str.length === 0) continue;
    parentNode.insertBefore(new Text(str), node);
  }

  parentNode.removeChild(node);
}

function main () {
  const TARGET_REGEXP = /world/i;
  const TARGET_SELECTOR = "div, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, span, strong";

  const tw = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    {acceptNode: createTextNodeFilterFn(TARGET_REGEXP, TARGET_SELECTOR)},
  );

  let node = tw.nextNode();

  while (node) {
    // Advance the TreeWalker's iterator state before mutating the current node:
    const memo = node;
    node = tw.nextNode();
    transformTextNode(memo, TARGET_REGEXP);
  }
}

main();
```

The TS code above, compiled to plain JavaScript in a runnable snippet:

```js
"use strict";
function assert(expr, msg) {
    if (!expr)
        throw new Error(msg);
}
function createTextNodeFilterFn(regexp, ancestorSelector) {
    return ((textNode) => {
        if (!(textNode.textContent
            && regexp.test(textNode.textContent)))
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        // To find any matching ancestor (not just the direct parent):
        // const valid = Boolean(textNode.parentElement?.closest(ancestorSelector));
        const valid = textNode.parentElement?.matches(ancestorSelector);
        if (valid)
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    });
}
function createSubstituteNode() {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "BARFOO";
    span.style.setProperty("color", "red");
    return span;
}
function transformTextNode(node, regexp) {
    const { parentNode, textContent } = node;
    assert(parentNode, "Parent node not found");
    assert(textContent, "Text content not found");
    const iter = textContent.split(regexp)[Symbol.iterator]();
    const firstResult = iter.next();
    if (firstResult.done)
        return;
    if (firstResult.value.length > 0) {
        parentNode.insertBefore(new Text(firstResult.value), node);
    }
    for (const str of iter) {
        parentNode.insertBefore(createSubstituteNode(), node);
        if (str.length === 0)
            continue;
        parentNode.insertBefore(new Text(str), node);
    }
    parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
function main() {
    const TARGET_REGEXP = /world/i;
    const TARGET_SELECTOR = "div, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, span, strong";
    const tw = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { acceptNode: createTextNodeFilterFn(TARGET_REGEXP, TARGET_SELECTOR) });
    let node = tw.nextNode();
    while (node) {
        // Advance the TreeWalker's iterator state before mutating the current node:
        const memo = node;
        node = tw.nextNode();
        transformTextNode(memo, TARGET_REGEXP);
    }
}
main();
```

```html
<div>
  hello world
  <p>
    the world is round
    <img src="domain.com/world.jpg">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - the understanding of how the DOM tree was being traversed helped me come up with a solution I think works. Take a look at my answer and see if you can spot any issues. Your treewalker solution looks solid, and I believe is achieving a similar result to mine now that I work from bottom to top. I'll need to read it a few more times to fully understand it operation.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465314/js-replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-word-in-html-with-span-element-only-for-p/75477328?noredirect=1#comment133170788_75477328) String manipulation of serialized DOM as HTML is error prone, and updating the DOM using [`Element.innerHTML = htmlStrring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) destroys all existing nodes within and any associated state (e.g. listeners, references).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465314/js-replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-word-in-html-with-span-element-only-for-p/75477328?noredirect=1#comment133170788_75477328) Direct node manipulation is safer and more performant: `TreeWalker` exists for cases exactly like this (where traversal is desired) and allows for very efficient iteration.

Comment: appreciate the explanation - accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a friend, explaining that the nodelist "array" returned by `querySelectorAll` is static, that explains why nodes were being missed or overwritten. The suggestion was to start at the lowest level of the DOM tree, perform the `innerHTML` replacement, then work up the tree.

Hat tip to Rob for his explanation: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a static nodelist which is accurate when the function is called but isn't accurate if the document is changed. Using `.innerHTML` to make the replacement of "world" deletes and recreates all existing content in the tag including the `<p>` tag and its contents the `<p>` tag that is now on the page is a completely new one that isn't referenced by the node returned by `document.querySelectorAll`

`querySelectorAll` returns an "array" (not quite, but the term is used loosely for purposes of this answer) using the depth-first traversal in pre-order operation. Read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal for tree traversal methods.

I needed to start at the lowest levels of the node arrays so as to not mangle any references to child nodes.

Here is the change:

(old)

`const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p, span, div, strong, h1, h2, h3, h4')).filter(`

(new)

`const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p, span, div, strong, h1, h2, h3, h4')).reverse().filter(`

On the sample html code in this question, and some other variations, it works fine. I'll continue to test further.

Comments / pitfalls welcomed.

New fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9vwo6a3q/